# Javascript Multiply 3 integers

Tags: javascript

My Javascript is off. I am a beginner.
I enter three numbers into three form fields. The addition works, but not the multiply. Also would love an average function. Here's the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<pre>

<form>
    NUMBER1:
    <input type="text" id="firstNumber" maxlength="100" size="20">
    <br>
    NUMBER2:
    <input type="text" id="secondNumber" maxlength="100" size="20">
    <br>
    NUMBER3:
    <input type="text" id="thirdNumber" maxlength="100" size="20">
    <br><br>
    <input name="Calculate Total" type="button" onclick="calculateText();" value="Add Total">
    <input type="text" id="Total" maxlength="100" size="20">
    <input name="Multiply Total" type="button" onclick="calculateText();" value="Multiply Total">
    <input type="text" id="multiplyresult" maxlength="100" size="20">

    </form>

</body>
</html>

function calculateText(){
    var number1=document.getElementById('firstNumber');
    var number2=document.getElementById('secondNumber');
    var number3=document.getElementById('thirdNumber');

    var result=document.getElementById('Total');
    var multiplyresult=document.getElementById('multipyTotal');

    var multiplyresult= number1 * number2  * number3; 

    if(number1.value=="" || number1.value!=parseFloat(number1.value)) number1.value=0;
    if(number2.value=="" || number2.value!=parseFloat(number2.value)) number2.value=0;
    if(number3.value=="" || number3.value!=parseFloat(number3.value)) number3.value=0;


    result.value=0;

    result.value=parseInt(result.value);

    result.value=parseInt(result.value)+parseInt(number1.value)+parseInt(number2.value)+parseInt(number3.value);
}
```

And in a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kamull61/2shG3/

Comment: why would you expect to be able to multiply **inputs** ala `number1 * number2 * number3` but have to add their **values** ala `parseInt(number1.value)+parseInt(number2.value)+parseInt(number3.value)` ? start there...

Answer (score 1):

My comment alluded to some problems with your code; I suspect coming from poor choice of variable names, and you've just confused yourself (we've all been there!). Here is an expanded comment to get you on the right track...

Start by creating better names for your variables:

```
//these are the input elements, not their values!
var number1Element = document.getElementById('firstNumber');
var number2Element = document.getElementById('secondNumber');
var number3Element = document.getElementById('thirdNumber');
```

Having done this, it should be obvious that you cannot do something like:

```
var multiplyresult = number1Element * number2Element * number3Element;
```

Since those variables represent the **input elements** and not their **values**.

Another thing to watch out for: you're declaring a variable `multiplyresult` as the input element for the multiply result, but then re-declaring that variable as the result of your (albeit erroneous) multiplication:

```
var multiplyresult = document.getElementById('multipyTotal');

var multiplyresult = number1 * number2 * number3;
```

Try to make variable names that are descriptive of what the variable represents, this is generally a good practice in programming. It becomes easier for you to spot issues with your code, and more importantly, makes the code easier to read and maintain by someone else in the future (including **you**, in the future!)

These are things you learn with time and practice - so keep at it!

Comment: That's really fantastic of you and I appreciate the encouragement.

Answer (score 0):

this was harder because of jsfiddle. onclick events couldn't connect with js below. Making it hard to do it that way. There are two more ways to attach events.

However, i got this take a look http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/2shG3/2/

shortcut for text to number is do some math operation with it instead of parsefloat and int. Works in some situations.

```
var  result=getId('Total'),
     multiplyresult=getId('multiplyresult'),
     n1,n2,n3;

function getValues(){ 
    n1=getId('firstNumber').value,
    n2=getId('secondNumber').value,
    n3=getId('thirdNumber').value;
}
console.log((n1)*(n2)*(n3));

window.addIt= function(){ getValues(); result.innerText=(+n1)+(+n2)+(+n3);};
window.multiply= function(){ getValues(); multiplyresult.innerText=(n1)*(n2)*(n3); };
function getId(x){ return document.getElementById(x);}
```